# Running spring tomcat app on heroku

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, heroku

I have a spring app that i am running on local tomcat using maven/intellij. I wanted to deploy it on heorko. When i just pushed the app (without any main class or procfile) i got the error that there is no application running.

I then followed this tutorial https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/create-a-java-web-application-using-embedded-tomcat

and added changes to `pom.xml`, created a `Main.java` class as suggested and created a `procfile` on root (where the pom.xml file is) and then i pushed it to heroku. I got the same error that application isn't running.

How can i run a spring tomcat app on heroku.

p.s:
Spring configurations are done using `<project_name>Configuration.java` class and `<project_name>Initializer.java`.

Answer (score 0):

Try following the guide for [Deploying Spring Boot Applications to Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-spring-boot-apps-to-heroku). If you're deploying a WAR file, try following the guide for [Deploying WAR Files](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment). Otherwise, you'll need to provide more info about your app.